# Is it grammatically correct to say 難しいことも、諦めたい時もあります?

Tags: grammar, particle-も

Hi this is my first question here, and I checked the database for questions like mine, but nothing came up.

Would it be grammatically correct to say

> もちろん、難しいことも、諦めたい時もあります。

My intention is to say

> Of course, difficult things and times when I wanted to give up existed too.

This is because I was taught that you could only put similar items in a category if you were to use Aも、Bもあります　such as ～ことも、～こともあります　but I was wondering if I could mix up things of different ”categories”.

I was also contemplating

> もちろん、難しいことも、諦めようと思ってこともあります。

Sorry if any are hideously and grammatically wrong. I am a beginner in the Japanese language.

Comment: "Difficult" as in "hardship" can best be translated to 辛い rather than 難しい. 難しい is used either for technical difficulty, possibility being thing, or a situation being subtle.

Answer (score 5):

The first phrase is grammatically correct. However, as you say the construction ～も～も sounds more natural if used with two things that are comparable, even if they don't have exactly the same form. For example, you could say

> 難しく感じること(orとき)も、｛諦めたい気持ちに/諦めたく｝なること(orとき)もあります。
>   Of course, there are times when I feel that it's (too) difficult or that I want to give up.

where you juxtapose two feelings. (Your original sentences places "things" next to "times".)

---

The second phrase is incorrect for purely grammatical reasons. You can't modify こと with 思って. The verb has to be in the 連体形 *rentaikei* form (identical to the dictionary form); here either 思う or 思っている.

> もちろん、困難なときも、諦めようと思うこともあります。

The above comments about style also apply here. You could also say

> もちろん、「難しい」とか「諦めたい」などと思うこともあります。
>   Of course, there are times when I just think "this is too difficult" or "I want to give up".

Comment: 例文、少し変えてもいいですか。

Comment: @chocolate Yes, please, any time. Thank you!

Comment: 二つ目がちょっと難しいです。「難しい**こと**も、諦めたい**とき・こと**もある」「難しい**こと**も、諦めようと思う**こと・とき**もある」というと、１つ目の「こと」は「物事, thing がある」って意味に読めてしまう一方で、二つ目の「こと」は「する場合, case/time がある」って意味なんで、この二つは「～も～も」で並べにくいです。一つ目の文のように、「～するとき(case/time)も～するとき(case/time)もある」とするか、「困難なとき」difficult times (もしくは「難しいとき」?)に変えてしまうか・・・というところです。

Answer (score 0):

The first phrase is correct.

The latter one is most likely no something that you would like to say because it doesn't establishes any connection between 「思って」 and 「こと」. You could say 「もちろん、難しいことも、諦めようと思って**いる時**もあります。」, though.